# How can I use filter to extract the desired value from the values ​of the double objects in the array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I have an object in an array called pick and I also have another object called diaryItem.

I also want to extract only the object whose name is wormColor from the diaryItem object.

so i tried my code but it doesn't work

error says v.filter is not a function

How can i fix my code?

```
const pick = [
    {
        diaryId: 1,
        diaryItem: { name: 'instar' }
    },
    {
        diaryId: 2,
        diaryItem: { name: 'facebook' }
    },
    {
        diaryId: 1,
        diaryItem: { name: 'wormColor' }
    },
]


const wormcolor = pick.map((v) => v.filter((p) => p.name ==="wormColor"))
```

expected answer

```
 wormcolor : [{
    diaryId: 2,
    diaryItem: { name: 'wormColor' }
    value: "2"
  }]
```

or

```
 wormcolor : {
    diaryId: 2,
    diaryItem: { name: 'wormColor' }
    value: "2"
  }
```

Comment: What is ````value```` in the expected result ?

Comment: your v variable will be an object, filter is not a function of an object. Just filter directly in pick rather than mapping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `map()` when you want to transform an array into another of same length by applying some function. That is not appropriate here.

Also, looking at your `filter()` callback, you are accessing `.name` directly, instead you want `.diaryItem.name`:

```js
const pick = [
    {
        diaryId: 1,
        diaryItem: { name: 'instar' }
    },
    {
        diaryId: 2,
        diaryItem: { name: 'facebook' }
    },
    {
        diaryId: 1,
        diaryItem: { name: 'wormColor' }
    }
]


const wormcolor = pick.filter((p) => p.diaryItem.name ==="wormColor");

console.log(wormcolor);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try it with filter

```
var lookingFor=pick.filter(function (el){
      return el.diaryItem.name=='wormColor';
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the object you get back then you would have to filter first and then map, something like this:

```js
const pick = [
  {
    diaryId: 1,
    diaryItem: { name: "instar" },
  },
  {
    diaryId: 2,
    diaryItem: { name: "facebook" },
  },
  {
    diaryId: 1,
    diaryItem: { name: "wormColor" },
  },
];

const wormcolor = pick
  .filter((item) => item.diaryItem.name === "wormColor")
  .map((filtered) => {
    return {
      ...filtered,
      value: filtered.diaryId + "",
    };
  });
```

What you get back from this should look like this: `[ { diaryId: 1, diaryItem: { name: 'wormColor' }, value: '1' } ]`.
If you do not want to change the original object then just skip the .map part.